# CONCAT function alternative in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use `CONCAT` function in SQL Server 2008. It doesn't work because it is not available in that version:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(Project, '-', FLOOR_ID)) AS value FROM dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY WHERE Project LIKE '%".$test_term."%'";
```

When i was google "How to" I found a post here said using `+` instead.  So I tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT( (Project + '-' + FLOOR_ID) ) AS value FROM dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY WHERE Project LIKE '%".$test_term."%'";
```

But i got this message:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' 22067-' to data type int.

So, how should i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting the `FLOOR_ID` to text:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Project + '-' + CAST(FLOOR_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS value
FROM dbo.IMP_MODEL_GEOMETRY
WHERE Project LIKE '%".$test_term."%'";
```

The current error message mentions the string `' 22067-'`, which implies that the `FLOOR_ID` is the source of the problem.

Comment: Excelent! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing datatypes for the `+` operation. In this case SQL server will attempt to convert VARCHAR expression to INT (this is done according to datatype precedence rules). You need to explicitly cast INT to VARCHAR:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Project, '')
     + '-'
     + COALESCE(CAST(FLOOR_ID AS VARCHAR(11)), '')
```

`CONCAT` function does not return NULL if the arguments are NULL. `COALESCE(..., '')` is required to match the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Cast `Project` and `FLOOR_ID` to String like this -

```
CAST(Project AS VARCHAR("MAX LENGTH OF PROJECT FIELD"))
```

and same for FLOOR_ID

Comment: Explain howto plz

Comment: CAST(Project AS VARCHAR("MAX LENGTH OF PROJECT FIELD")) and same for FLOOR_ID